# changing argument #0 to a shell script not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to replace parameter `$0`/`argv[0]`. If I compile this c code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  printf("# %s #\n", argv[0]);
}
```

and then run it with `exec -a fake ./run`, I get the output

```
# fake #
```

I then tried with the following shell script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "# $0 #"
```

but when I run `exec -a fake ./test.sh` I get

```
# /home/user/test.sh #
```

Why is argument 0 being reset somewhere in the shell script case?

For reference, here is the relevant part of `exec --help`

```
exec: exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]
    Replace the shell with the given command.

    Execute COMMAND, replacing this shell with the specified program.
    ARGUMENTS become the arguments to COMMAND.  If COMMAND is not specified,
    any redirections take effect in the current shell.

    Options:
      -a name   pass NAME as the zeroth argument to COMMAND
      -c        execute COMMAND with an empty environment
      -l        place a dash in the zeroth argument to COMMAND
```

Comment: The answer is here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/717673/8215

Comment: Remove the shebang line and it'll work.

Comment: @oguzismail it will work in this simplified test scenario, but not in my real scenario where I am using `execve` from a c program, not `exec` from the shell

Comment: If it's so important you can re-implement what execve does with scripts and change arg. 0 before actually calling execve. The manpage for execve is pretty detailed

Comment: Note that if you've got Bash 5.0 or later you can use the [BASH_ARGV0](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-BASH_005fARGV0) special variable to change `$0`/`argv[0]` from inside a Bash program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run with strace:

```
$ strace -fe execve bash -c 'exec -a fake ./test.sh'
execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "exec -a fake ./test.sh"], 0x7ffd9c557aa0 /* 56 vars */) = 0
execve("/home/xxx/test.sh", ["fake"], 0x58fc3a91a130 /* 56 vars */) = 0

# /home/xxx/test.sh #
```

you will notice that "fake" *is* passed as zeroth argument, it's just <strike>shell overrides $0 with script name</strike>

indeed, as @oguz pointed out, this is the special case of [interpreter scripts handling by exec commands](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html#:%7E:text=An%20interpreter%20script%20is).

Compare with the same shell script but without #!/bin/bash :

```
$ strace -fe execve bash -c 'exec -a fake ./test.sh' 
execve("/usr/bin/ksh", ["ksh", "-c", "exec -a fake ./test.sh"], 0x7fff79964a40 /* 56 vars */) = 0
execve("/home/xxx/test.sh", ["fake"], 0x5fbe079d0b08 /* 57 vars */) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
# fake #
```

Comment: It's execve that overwrites argv[0], the manual even warns about it: *Note that  there is no way to get the argv[0] that was passed to the execve() call.*

Comment: @oguzismail where is this said?  and check my update

Comment: Here https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html#:~:text=Note%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20that%20there%20is%20no%20way%20to%20get%20the%20argv%5B0%5D%20that%20was%20passed%20to%20the%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20execve()%20call.

Comment: @oguzismail thanks, didn't know that, not so obvious as I thought

Answer (score 2):

> Why is argument 0 being reset somewhere in the shell script case?

This is [Bash's documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for `$0`:

> Expands to the name of the shell or shell script. This is set at shell initialization. If `bash` is invoked with a file of commands, `$0` is set to the name of that file. If `bash` is started with the `-c` option, then `$0` is set to the first argument after the string to be executed, if one is present. Otherwise, it is set to the file name used to invoke `bash`, as given by argument zero.

When you use a shebang line in your script to execute it as if it were a binary, the system turns that into an execution of the specified interpreter, with the erstwhile command name as its first argument (and the rest of the command-line arguments following).  Something analogous to this C function call, in your case:

```
execlp("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", "./test.sh", (char *) NULL);
//      ^            ^            ^
//      |            |            |
// interpreter  interpreter  path-to-script
//                 arg 0        arg 1
```

The original argument 0 is irrecoverably lost.

This behavior is documented for Linux in terms of the [underlying `execve()` function](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).

The command name you set at the shell level via `exec -a` is doubly irrelevant here, because not only is it discarded as described above, but even if it were passed through as argument 0 to the shell running your script, your case is "***If `bash` is invoked with a file of commands***" from that shell's perspective.  That yields `test.sh` as you observe.

In a Bash script, if you want to know the pathname by which bash read the current source file, use `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`.